# Why do I need a `try_files` to make the `root` directive work?

Tags: nginx

I was having troubles making nginx find the static files for my frontend, and I added a seemingly-tautological `try_files` instruction, which made everything work.

```
  location /frontend {
      try_files $uri /;
  }

  root {{ static_root }};
  index /frontend/index.html;

  location / {
      rewrite ^.*$ /frontend/index.html break;
  }
```

My question is: why wouldn't this work without the first `location /frontend` directive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rewrite` is a indiscriminate, it applies to every request (even `.css` and `.js` files). By adding a separate `location`, URIs beginning with `/frontend` are protected from the indiscriminate `rewrite`.

You could probably achieve a similar result with:

```
root /path/to/root;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /frontend/index.html;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'll leave it as it is now since it's a tad more explicit